UNITY SHADERS - Can't face sides in the right direction
I'm trying to make a shader where every side except for top and bottom face upwards. In addition, I want it to not change the scale of my image no matter the size of the object the material is applied to. I just need to rotate the faces on the side clockwise 90 degrees.
Shader "Custom/Tiling"
{
Properties {




_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
_Scale("Texture Scale", Float) = 1.0
}
SubShader {
Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert
    
    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _Color;
    float _Scale;
    
    struct Input {
        float3 worldNormal;
        float3 worldPos;
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };
    
    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        float2 UV;
        fixed4 c;
    
        if (abs(IN.worldNormal.x) > 0.5) {
            UV = IN.worldPos.yz; // side
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALLSIDE texture
        }
        else if (abs(IN.worldNormal.z) > 0.5) {
            UV = IN.worldPos.xy; // front
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALL texture
           
        }
        else {
            UV = IN.worldPos.xz; // top
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use FLR texture
        }
    
        o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
    }
    ENDCG
    }
    
    Fallback "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit"

}

I tried to rotate the uvs and couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm very new to Unity's shaders.
